# dealing with full mongodb-atlas database

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I have set up a free tier MongoDB-atlas database and have a script that is storing tweets on it. Using db.collection.stats() it says storage size is 32768 which will fill up quite fast. Firstly, what happens when you exceed this limit? are new entries rejected or something else? Secondly, is there a way to deal with this without upgrading? For example, is it possible to clear entries before exceeding capacity?

Answer (score 0):

When you exceed the limit the atlas cluster node will have exceeded the limit will be unavailable. It may be possible that the entire cluster will go down and then you will need to contact the MongoDB support to make the cluster up.

Although the best option is this that you need to upgrade to next tier for having more storage capacity. But in case you don't want that in that case you may write a script to delete old data from your cluster and after deleting the data make sure to run the compact command to reclaim the data storage.